# Need player object within Player class

Tags: java, oop

In the initPlayerOnJoin I need to access the player's balance. It's mostly likely a easy fix but I'm still learning the concepts of OOP.

```
 public class Player {

private String name;
private Stock stock;
private Integer balance;


  public Player(String name) {

    this.setName(name);

    initPlayerOnJoin(this);
  }

  private static void initPlayerOnJoin(Player player) {
    player.addBalance(500);
  }
  public void addBalance(Integer amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }
}
```

Comment: use 'getters' and 'setters' to set a players balance and then consequently get their balance

Comment: write a getter method in Player class

Comment: One rule of thumb in OOP is that `static` methods are rarely needed; `initPlayerOnJoin` seems redundant to me, how are you using the `Player`?

Comment: Why is everyone asking him to use getters? First of all, have you tested your codes? Do you know you still can get balance without a getter because `person` is the same class as `Person`???

Comment: @Hypnoatic Can you explain what `initPlayerOnJoin()` is supposed to do. It looks weird to me that you are inserting `this` into that method. Do you know what is `this` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Player {

private String name;
private Stock stock;
private Integer balance;


  public Player(String name) {

    this.setName(name);

    initPlayerOnJoin(this);
  }

//To get the balance
  public Integer getBalance() { return balance; }

  private static void initPlayerOnJoin(Player player) {
    player.addBalance(500);
  }
  public void addBalance(Integer amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public class Player {

private String name;
private Stock stock;
private Integer balance;


public Player(String name) {

this.setName(name);

initPlayerOnJoin(this);
}

//To get the balance
public Integer getBalance() {     return balance; }

private static void   initPlayerOnJoin(Player player) {
player.addBalance(getBalance());
}
public void addBalance(Integer amount) {
balance += amount;
}
}
```

Comment: I hope you realize that `player.addBalance(getBalance());` will not only not compile in this context (calling non-static from static), but would *double* the player's balance?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement getters and setters. But since player is of the same type i.e `Player`. Even **without getters** and even though the variables are **private** you **still can** read the data.

```
 private void initPlayerOnJoin(Player player) {
    addBalance(player.blanace);
 }
```

However without accessors(getters), other classes will not be able to access `balance`, so you can still create a getter method.

**With getters:**

```
 private void initPlayerOnJoin(Player player) {
    addBalance(player.getBlanace());  //assuming you adding to yourself
 }
 public Integer getBalance(){
    return balance;
 }
```

P.S: I don't see a point of declaring your methods as `static`. 
Static methods belongs to the class, not individual instance.

**When to use private static methods?**

Normally static methods are `public` like those in the utility classes. If your method is private. You only declare it as static when you want to use that method to access some static variables within the class itself.

On top of that, all your variables are declared with wrapper class, not primitive datatype. You could simply use `int`, `double` instead of `Integer`, `Double`.